# Can I use a custom model with Django's authentication system?

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I wrote a custom backend for my application to process logins in a sort-of unique way, as I have specific needs for this project. Here's my backend:

```
from my.project.models import User 
from hashlib import sha512

class MyBackend:

    def authenticate(self, email_address=None, password=None):
        print "Trying to auth: " + email_address

        try: 
            user = User.objects.get(email_address=email_address)
            password = sha512(password + user.password_salt).hexdigest()

            if user.password != password:
                return None
            else:
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Here's my `User` class:

```
class User(models.Model):
    email_address = models.EmailAddressField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    password_salt = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

It's pretty simple, but I've already built the rest of my models around this 'User' class.

Is there a way to make this work so as to have the best of both worlds, or should I ditch this approach and just use Django's built-in model for users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending the user can best be done by using [user profiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_profile). 
Define a user profile-model and at the bottom, add something like this:

```
User.profile = property(lambda u: Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

I think this approach might be better than replacing the User-model

Comment: So, if I'm understanding you properly, create a model with a one-to-one with a Django auth User object, and use my authentication system to handle the special login stuff? Am I understanding it right? What exactly does the code above do? (Familiar with Python, but not with `lamda` blocks)

Comment: Could you rewrite your answer to demonstrate exactly what to do? That would be really helpful, and I'd definitely award you the answer.

Comment: Sure. There is an old article which might be a good introduction: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/ Additionally, see the section in the django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users .My example adds the "profile"-property to the User-class; done this way, you can get a profile easily by something like "u = User.objects...()" and "u.profile". If the profile does not exist, it creates it (see the get_or_create()-documentation).

Comment: This works for accessing your model, but it requeries on **every** access, which is bad for in terms of performance and you can't modify it in memory.